# Hook to add a button (link) when creating new page/post from admin

Tags: wordpress

Could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish a small task?
Basically I need to create a small plugin that adds a button (html code - a link) on the add new page/post in admin.

I've researched a bit but I didn't find what hook to use. Thank you

Comment: Please provide a brief overview on what you have tried so far. Also, are you trying to add a button automatically when you create a new post ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add a button somewhere on the post new page in admin that once clicked would trigger some ajax.
Here's what I've come up with in case someone else needs this:

```
add_action( 'media_buttons', function($editor_id){
        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="do_something()" class="button" id="ajaxbutton">Click me</a>';
    });
```